# view_facts permission doesn't work in foreman restful API

Tags: permissions, puppet, foreman

I met a foreman restful API issue when I am using foreman 1.7.4 version.

When I try to use an account with view_facts permission to query facts of a given host via foreman restful API, it just show empty, while I could query facts of a given host in web interface.

I could query facts through restful API only when I have given account admin permission, which is not I wanted. because admin permission could not only query but also change/write something.

Given view_facts permission but not admin

curl -s -k -u user:passwd -H "Accept: version=2,application/json" https://sjengpptmst01/api/hosts/test.sample.com/facts

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 20,
  "search": " host = test.sample.com",
  "sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
  },
  "results": {}
}
```

Gavin admin permission

```
{
  "total": 22066,
  "subtotal": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 20,
  "search": " host = test.sample.com",
  "sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
  },
  "results": {"test.sample.com": 
   {"root_home":"/root","path":"/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin","rubysitedir":"/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8","puppet_vardir":"/var/lib/puppet","unlabeled_dev_count":"0\n","macaddress_eth0":"00:50:56:A9:F0:DC","macaddress":"00:50:56:A9:F0:DC","bios_release_date":"06/22/2012","uniqueid":"090a444c","augeasversion":"1.0.0","rubyversion":"1.8.7","network_eth0":"10.9.76.0","ipaddress":"10.9.76.68","ipaddress_eth0":"10.9.76.68","blockdevice_sr0_size":"1073741312","network_lo":"127.0.0.0","ipaddress_lo":"127.0.0.1","uptime_hours":"143","mtu_eth0":"1500","facterversion":"2.4.3"}}
}
```

But when I use firefox to visit the given host with given accout without admin permission, it could show facts on web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported as Foreman [bug #9793](http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/9793) and it was fixed in Foreman 1.9.0, so you should consider upgrading from 1.7 to a newer release.

When upgrading, it's recommended that you go through each major release as jumps across multiple releases aren't tested and may have problems.

http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.8/index.html#3.6Upgrade
http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/index.html#3.6Upgrade
http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.10/index.html#3.6Upgrade

The stable release at the time of writing is 1.10.x, with 1.11.x in release candidate status.

Comment: I tried to use REST API v1 and it works. I think I could use APIv1 temporarily.